# Excel: create formula from other cells so that numbers and words are shown

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to create regression equations from design of experiments data.

Take this data:

[image]

Now I want to write d = 0.004157 + A * (0.002942 +- 0.0006) + B * (0.003116 +- 0.0007) + C * (0.003509+-0.0008) into one cell. This means the formula consists of every line, where Term * (Coef +- SE Coef)

When creating formulas normally, words cannot be included. The formula can be shown in excel, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Sure you can put words in a formula: `="d = " & C2 & "+ A *(" & C3`... and so on.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to do it with just selecting the cell and without typing "+ A *(" every time?

Comment: Change to `"+ " & A3 & "*(` or something similar?

Comment: "...without typing ... every time" -- You do know that when formulas are copied from once cell to another, Excel adjusts the references?

Comment: Thank you, it works. I hoped there was a function to just enter + and = without the need of "" and &

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes you're right, but sometimes there are less or more lines so it is still some struggle for larger datasets